# address tag in Vue template breaks lint

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, vue-cli

I have a Vue JS component like this

```
<template>
    <footer class="main-footer">
        <p> <address>Some address</address> </p>
    </footer>
</template>
```

When I run `vue-cli-service lint`, it changes the opening `<p>` to `<p />` and issues the following error

```
error: Parsing error: x-invalid-end-tag (vue/no-parsing-error) at src/components/Footer.vue:3:46:
  1 | <template>
  2 |     <footer class="main-footer">
> 3 |         <p /><address>Some address</address> </p>
    |                                              ^
```

In fact, in my Webstorm, the closing `</p>` is marked in red `Closing tag matches nothing`.

I took the `address` tag out and it works perfectly. Is there any reason I can't use address tag?

Here is my `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true
    },
    extends: [
        'plugin:vue/recommended',
        '@vue/standard'
    ],
    rules: {
        'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
        'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
        indent: ['error', 4],
        'space-before-function-paren': ['warn', 'never'],
        'vue/require-default-prop': 'off',
        'vue/no-v-html': 'off',
        'vue/html-indent': ['error', 4]
    },
    parserOptions: {
        parser: 'babel-eslint'
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            files: [
                '**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)',
                '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)'
            ],
            env: {
                jest: true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That because ```<p />``` itself indicates single tag.

Paired tags are written as ```<p>something</p>```. Now the question is - why does it change the ```<p>`` tag?

Comment: Trying to fix this lint errors automatically using the ```--fix``` keyword might cause this

Comment: @DeepakTerse Even when it's written as `<p>...</p>` Webstorm says `closing tag matches nothing`. It seems like the address tag is causing the issue

Comment: This is probably because you are using ```<address>``` which is a block level element inside a ```<p>``` tag which itself is a block level element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

The error is that you're placing a `</p>` tag which has no starting `<p>` tag. That's because what you think is the starting tag is automatically closed by the parser, in accordance to the [official HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), because of `<address>` tag following the `<p>` tag.

---

**Longer (initial) answer:**

This is the expected behavior, as specified by the official spec ([HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element)). Respectively:

> A `p` element's end tag can be omitted if the `p` element is immediately followed by an `address`, `article`, `aside`, `blockquote`, `details`, `div`, `dl`, `fieldset`, `figcaption`, `figure`, `footer`, `form`, `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `header`, `hgroup`, `hr`, `main`, `menu`, `nav`, `ol`, `p`, `pre`, `section`, `table`, or `ul` element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is an HTML element that is not an `a`, `audio`, `del`, `ins`, `map`, `noscript`, or `video` element, or an autonomous custom element.

Which causes your `<p>` element to be automatically closed when the `<address>` element is met by the parser.

Since you obviously don't want this behavior, you should use a  `<div>` instead of a `<p>` element here, although, considering the markup in your question, perhaps you should ditch the wrapper altogether (i.e: `footer > address`).

Comment: Makes sense. So what happens if the `p` is not immediately followed by an address? Such as `<p>something else<address>...`?

Comment: In that case `'something else'` is considered contents of `<p>` and, technically, it's followed by a `<address>` tag. Browsers should close the `<p>` tag when they meet an `<address>` inside it's "contents". Basically your example is the same as `<p>something else</p><address>...` The spec says you don't have to use the `</p>` tag in this case, it's automatically added. An often missed part of the spec is: *"The `p` element should not be used when a more specific element is more appropriate."*

Answer (score 2):

From MDN: "Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing `</p>` tag".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p